# Checking if user is using a specific locale

Tags: android

I need to check if the locale of a user's device is Japanese. I'm doing the following:

```
public boolean isJapaneseLocale() {
    String locale = Locale.getDefault().toString();
    locale = locale.toLowerCase();
    return locale.startsWith("ja");
}
```

should that be sufficient? I'm getting a warning about:

```
locale.toLowerCase()
```

and using the default locale for that. Is this not safe for this operation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an older way of doing things.  But since locales don't use non-ascii characters, it shouldn't be a problem.  Just ignore the warning, or suppress it if using Eclipse.